# HTML & PHP input[] <- array ? Limitations

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

It's more of a wether can someone confirm my theory, as for going short ways, when you add another `input` which shall have similar name ex. `myvar_0`, `myvar_1` you are supposed to use `javascript` to generate those `inputs`, but there is `input "array" type`, where you crate an `input` with name `myvar[]`, `myvar[]`, `myvar[]` and this acts as an `array` and passes values via `post` to PHP as an `array`, but recently i've discovered that for some weird reason this `array` has limitation of `197 values` ( or 196 is the maximum capable index value ) as on `chrome` for now ( didn't text it on other browser ).

So does anyone else encoutered a similar problem ?

Comment: Using GET or POST? There's a maximum query limit on GET requests -- that may be the issue, rather than something specific to `[]`.

Comment: what is the length of your url when using GET? maybe this can help: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Comment: @shane So he does, good spot.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `suhosin`, that brings a limit to the `max_vars` sent via POST.
Default is set to 200, so could be your problem.

See: [suhosin.post.max_vars](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_vars)

Answer (score 2):

array format got nothing to do with html or browser , for browser square brackets doesn't mean any special thing it will send all the key , value pairs with same key as opt[] e.x

for

```
<input type="hidden name="opt[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden name="opt[]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden name="opt[]" value="3"/>
```

browser will send

```
opt[]=1
opt[] =2
opt[]=3
```

as a request to the server;

Its the PHP which is smart enough to interpret this as index array with name of "opt" .

Comment: @Bamboo - You missed the whole point of the answer: it's not a browser feature at all. It's a server-side (PHP) feature.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a simple test (See below) which returns (for me) 200 items in a post array.

```
<form method="post">
<?php

print count($_POST['opt']);

for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++){
?><input type="hidden" name="opt[]" value="1" /><?php
}

?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I get the impression this is more about the data being sent, or the server itself, than a limitation of PHP.

Comment: Just tested with 20000 elements, still fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was the Suhoshin security module, after some research i found that acually max_post_vars was set to 200, that was kinda blocking the rest of data from being processed, thanks for all your answer :-)